# Динамическое удаление элементов меню bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, set

Я пытаюсь удалить часть элементов из менюшки программно в активности при выполнении условий. Делаю так:

```
if (!sp!!.getStringSet("disabled_app_modules", HashSet<String>()).isNullOrEmpty()) {
 val set = sp!!.getStringSet("disabled_app_modules", HashSet<String>())
 when {
   set.contains("notepad") -> {
     bottomNavigationView.menu.removeItem(R.id.notespec)
   }
 }
}
```

но так ничего не работает. Если напрямую после объявления виджета удалять элемент то все работает нормально:

```
bottomNavigationView.menu.removeItem(R.id.notespec)
```

думал сделать так:

```
bottomNavigationView.postInvalidate()
```

но не помогло. Думал проблема в том что пустой сет приходит, но сет в памяти есть и он не пустой. Проблема где-то в этих строках:

```
set.contains("notepad") -> {
     bottomNavigationView.menu.removeItem(R.id.notespec)
   }
```

но тут я не знаю где могут быть проблемы, вроде все правильно записано, или нет...

### UPDATE

Есть гипотеза почему не находятся элементы, но мне она кажется не очень правдоподобной. Вот мой сет:

```
<set name="disabled_app_modules">
   <string>&quot;notepad&quot;</string>
</set>
```

а я ищу `set.contains("notepad")` может еще нужно как-то учитывать скобки или это бред?

Comment: Это не бред, это два разных слова

Comment: да но как-то пока удалить `&quot;` не получается))

Comment: hash вашего текста и текста в переменной не совпадает, вот поэтому не находится

Comment: мне вот непонятно почему просто string сохраняет без скобок, а если сет сохранять то какой-то затык получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему, возможно и костыльно но работает нормально:

```
val set = sp!!.getStringSet("disabled_app_modules", HashSet<String>())
val list: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
list.addAll(set!!)

for (i in 0 until list.size){
   when(list[i].substring(1,list[i].length-1)){

      "notepad"->{
         bottomNavigationView.menu.removeItem(R.id.notespec) 
       }
    }

}
```

в итоге делает то что нужно. Может поможет кому :)

Comment: Да, только вы увеличили сложность, вместо O(1), стало O(N)

Comment: не понял, уточните пожалуйста что вы имеете в виду :(

Comment: вы увеличили алгоритмическую сложность алгоритма. Вместо моментального определения, есть ли элемент в последовательности, теперь нужно пройтись по всем элементам и проверять подходит ли элемент. И да у вас выполняется проверка для всех элементов.
К тому же вы еще используете substring(), что как я помню, под капотом влечет создание new String(), на каждом этапе, что тоже не очень хорошо

Comment: @danilshik, с учетом того что мне тут пока что ничего не предложили, выложил то что есть у меня))

Comment: не легче ли было просто удалить &quot

Comment: я пробовал но, если делать через replace то не находит такого элемента в строке)) это первое что я пробовал)